# Https request wth user auth rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
curl -u "token:53555" https://url/method
```

how to send token in Net::Http url,  I tried as

```
uri = URI.parse(url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri,{'token' => '53555'})
response = http.request(request)
```

But its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
uri = URI.parse(url + "?token=53555")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
response = http.request(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

`request['authorization'] = "Token token=#{token}"` Set token like this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **basic_auth** to your request object. Like so:

```
uri = URI.parse(url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
request.basic_auth 'token', '53555'
response = http.request(request)
```

The **`request.basic_auth 'token', '53555'`** is the line that adds the basic authentication code.